# regarding adding labels inside the figure

Tags: r

I have a data set as follows:

```
  group  ratio
  0-0.2    58%
0.2-0.4    68%
0.4-0.6    60%
0.6-0.8    80%
```

I would like to visualize the above data set in the following figure,

[image]

How can I achieve this in R, especially adding those labels, e.g., 68%, inside the figure?

Comment: Don't use R only for visualization; you can use it to generate statistics (in your case breaks with .2 steps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather more reusable solution;

```
data<-runif(1000)
myLab<-diff(unlist(lapply(seq(0,1,0.2), function(y){sum(data<y)})))*100/length(data)
hist(data,breaks=seq(0,1,0.2), labels =paste0(myLab,"%"), col ="yellow")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring repeating the non-zero y-axis, something like this will work:

```
x <- c(58, 68, 60, 80)
savplot <- barplot(x,space=0,col="yellow",border=NA)
axis(1,at=0:length(x),labels=seq(0,0.8,0.2))
par(xpd=NA)
text(labels=paste0(x,"%"),savplot,x+5,cex=1.5)
par(xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]